# Check if Mail setup is done on IOS device via code

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can you please let me know in xcode how to check if the Mail setup is done?
Ex : If Device A has Mail(Exchange) setup then it should return YES anf if not then NO.

So can we access this mail settings via code?If yes then Please let me know the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [self doStuff];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that.
But can you also let me know is there any way to check if the outlook(Exchange) is integrated or synced? 
Ex:Like we have different mail services gmail,outlook , yahoo etc.. So I want to check if the mail service is outlook ?So can we?

Comment: I'm afraid not. iOS that handle this part of logic.